# PySpark Set Column value equal to another dataframe value if rows match

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Hi I want to check a spark dataframe column value and set it based on checking if the row name matches with another dataframe row.

Example:

```
df1:
average name
3.5      n1
1.2      n2
4.2      n3

df2:
name    
n1     
n1        
n1    
n2
n3
n1
n2
n3
n3

df_i_want:
average name
3.5      n1
3.5      n1
3.5      n1
1.2      n2
4.2      n3
3.5      n1
1.2      n2
4.2      n3
4.2      n3
```

Comment: why are you guys down voting please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you needed to do was a `Join`

You can achieve the result like below.

Join your data frame `df2` with `df1` on `name` and the select the order of columns you want

```
df3 = df2.join(df1, on = 'name').select('average', 'name')
```

The above code snippet should give you the desired result

Answer (score 2):

You need a join to do this task:

```
## join both data on name
df3 = df2.join(df1, on='name',how='left')

# change column sequence
df3 = df3.select('average','name')

# order by name values
df3 = df3.orderBy('name', ascending=True)
```